# Braintree client: form submission failure

Tags: javascript, braintree

I am totally new to braintree and was just trying out the tutorial (javascript for client and JAVA on the server side)

I created a simple HTML file basically just wrapping the "Hello Client" [example](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+java/start/hello-client). I had also tried using both the given clientToken provided in the example and one I obtained from the sandbox account.

However, after I filled out a valid credit information and tried to submit the form, I've got this error:

"There was an error processing your request. Try again"

And this error occurred BEFORE the form submission was actually sent to the server; braintree.js seems to have intercepted the submission and did some authorization with its server, and thats where the error above came from

I looked at the chrome developer console and saw the requests were like this:

```
Request URL:https://client-analytics.sandbox.braintreegateway.com
Params:
authorizationFingerprint: [some fp]
sharedCustomerIdentifierType:undefined
analytics[][kind]:dropin.web.inline.add-card.fail
_meta[platform]:web
_meta[platformVersion]: [some value]
_meta[integrationType]:dropin
_meta[sdkVersion]:braintree/web/2.3.3
_meta[merchantAppId]:file:///Users/jiayaohan/Desktop/card.html
braintreeLibraryVersion:braintree/web/2.3.3
_method:POST
callback:callback_json9
```

And the status code itself was OK (200), but in the response, the content was:

```
callback_json9({status:201})
```

Anyone knows what might go wrong with this very simple hello-world client setup? (noted that I've tried using both the given example client Token and one derived from my own sandbox account, but the same error happened)

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree.</sub>

It looks like there was a failure adding a card. Are you using the available testing card credentials?

Sandbox only accepts [certain test numbers](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+java/reference/general/testing#credit-card-numbers), so that could be your issue. The most commonly used test number is `4111111111111111`.

Comment: I had the same problem. When submit form with card number e.g. `4242 4242 4242 4242` I couldn't use this again. So have to use some other number from braintree docs. Hope this help.

Comment: Hi, I have never face this issue in sandbox mode but now I'm in production, I'm trying to pay for a 1$ service (that I manually added to my database for testing purpose) and I have this error while my credit card information are good. Can you please help ?